# Spring Boot web app deployed to Ubuntu returning PDF containing a currency symbol (¤) rather than a dollar sign ($)

Tags: java, spring-boot, ubuntu, pdf

I have a Spring Boot web app that generates a PDF (as a ByteArrayOutputStream) and returns it (ByteArrayInputStream) as an attachment from an endpoint.  When running the app locally (MacOS) the PDF correctly contains dollar signs ($).  I have deployed the web to an Ubuntu server on AWS.  When calling the endpoint from the Ubuntu deployment, the PDF contains a currency symbol (¤) instead of a dollar sign ($) for each occurrence.  I cannot determine why this is happening.

Ubuntu version: `Linux ip-172-31-92-87 5.15.0-1023-aws #27-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 20 16:44:17 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

The currency symbol showing up in the pdf: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00A4

Relevant java endpoint code:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/invoice/upload", produces = { "application/pdf" })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
...
) { 
   // ...code that generates pdf...
   String contentDispositionValue = "attachment; filename=\"" + simpleFilename + "\"";

        ByteArrayInputStream pdfInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfOutputStream.toByteArray());

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("content-disposition", contentDispositionValue);

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentLength(pdfOutputStream.size())
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
                .body(new InputStreamResource(pdfInputStream));

    }
```

I have tried adding a header "Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=utf-8" but that didn't work either.

I am using the following dependency in the pom.xml that is used to generate the pdf:

```
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?  And how can I prevent the currency symbol from showing up in the PDF and have it use dollar signs as intended.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would depend on the locales of the server and client.  Are they different?

Comment: How an I determine the locales?

Comment: Just a guess, but I think that it's more likely that the problem exists in the code that generates the PDF content.

Comment: But what would explain the difference between running it locally (and getting the correct $ in PDF) vs running it on Ubuntu (and getting the currency symbol)?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was locale.  Thanks, Jim Garrison.  I fixed the issue by adding the following statement to the endpoint method:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
```